# Disabling object OnCollisionEnter and Enabling it On Collision exit

Tags: unity, c#, collision-detection

I have two objects that when they collide disable another gameobject. The problem is that I only want to have the other game object disabled while the two objects are touching and that I want to have it enabled again as soon as the two objects are no longer touching. My script is below:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class DestroyObject : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject ObjectToDestroy;
public GameObject TheObject;
public GameObject Player;

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)    {
    if (col.gameObject == TheObject) {
        ObjectToDestroy.SetActive (false);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What happens when you do `OnCollisionExit() { if (col.gameObject == TheObject) { ObjectToDestroy.SetActive(true); } }`   Why doesn't that work?

Comment: Thanks. I already tried that and you made me realize a mistake. Instead of putting (Collision col) as an argument, I put down (Collider col). Simple mistake.

Comment: Ah, yeah that will get you ;)  cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue as I noticed a simple mistake that I made when I was trying to fix this myself. Here is the whole piece of code.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class DestroyObject : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject ObjectToDestroy;
public GameObject TheObject;
public GameObject Player;

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)    {
    if (col.gameObject == TheObject) {
        ObjectToDestroy.SetActive (false);
    }
}

void OnCollisionExit(Collision col) { 
    if (col.gameObject == TheObject) {
        ObjectToDestroy.SetActive (true);
    }
}
}
```